# Can't view lower section of website when viewing under any view in Safari

Tags: javascript, css

I have been working on the following photo site which can scroll through to the bottom in chrome:

http://www.jpdgallery.com/

The last visible section of the site is an instagram iframe. The other remaining sections are a modal which pops up when a photo is selected, and a contact form which slides over from the left.

When I am in Safari, even in a Chrome responsive developer view, the page only scrolls until about halfway through the iframe. I tried removing the iframe, module, and slide-over, just to diagnose, and the page would only scroll halfway through the gallery.

I have also tried various height setting adjustments on html, body and everything within, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was an overflow hidden issue on the body that was only causing an issue in safari. This was resolved by simply removing the property.